# Происхождение слова "ништяк"

Tags: жаргон, этимология

Я снова с жаргонизмами — очень интересно узнавать их происхождение. На этот раз меня интересует слово "ништяк".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, окказиональное образование от нЕчто.

Вот [здесь](http://ru-etymology.livejournal.com/24001.html) (осторожно, ненормативная лексика) обсуждается подобная версия: от "ничто", но авторы сами признают натяжку. Ништяк (правильнее бы было "нештяк") куда более продуктивно.

Answer (score 1):

"Ништяк" - жаргонизм от "ничего" в ответ на, к примеру, "Как жизнь?". То есть когда в американских фильмах говорят "Отлично!" в ответ на подобный вопрос (How are You?, правда, скорее это не вопрос, а приветствие) отвечающий имеет в виду наш "ништяк". В ходе развития "ништяк" стал и "Ну, дает!", "нормально", "хорошо (хороший)" и еще много чем.

Говорят "ништяк" появился в 70-х, но я прекрасно помню его в самом начале 60-х в речи приятелей постарше. Из форумов: *"Кстати о ништяке, есть маза, что тогда в моде были "яки", а также в ходу выражение "ништо" (от "ничего") типа "ништё, не бзди, прорвемся". Я думаю, что "ништяк" прямиком оттуда. Сегодня, похоже, от "яков" остался один только "неудобняк". А жаль!"*

От себя добавлю: есть еще "головняк", означающее большое неудобство (от "головная боль"), "сушняк" (охота пить с бодуна, а лучше опохмелиться), "верняк" и т. п.

Comment: @tmp - спасибо, использовал Вашу ссылку для более развернутого ответа.

Answer (score 1):

"Ништяк" или "Ничтяк" я впервые услышал в одном из пригородов Волгограда, где мы были на непрофильной практике - отработке в 1965-м. Какой-то местный молодой лоботряс употребил его с таким видом: вот, мол, что мы знаем. То есть, судя по тому, как цвело его лицо, он только что где-то его услышал и тут же поспешил нам передать. Смысл этого слова ("Всё в порядке"), может быть и не единственный, был понятен сразу, слово показалось  дурацким как, и многие другие "верняки", к блатной лексике, которую я немного понимал, оно, думаю, прямого отношения не имело.
"Сушняк", правда, нет-нет да долбил по утрам. От этого слова не могу отречься.
Это моё мнение. Кому что нравится. Народ очень часто кучкуется, само собой, по возрасту, по месту работы, жительства, по стилю речи и многим другим признакам. Если компания не устраивает, можно всегда примкнуть к другой, пока молодой.
Будьте здоровы.